# Jquery: How to get Table cell value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
<table class="table" align="center" id="tblMain">
  <tr>
      <td>Status</td>
      <td><b><span name="current" value="Dispatch">Dispatch</span></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('#tblMain').find('td').ready(function() 

if( $('#current').val() == 'Dispatch')
{
    alert('Dispatch');
}
else
{
     alert('Nothing found');
}
);
```

I need table cell value to compare with with my status and should alert as given ..how to achieve this?

Comment: `span` don't have `value` attribute. Invalid HTML;

Comment: Please correct your HTML sample. You have no closing `</span>` and not close on the `</b`.

Answer (score 3):

1. `<span>` don't have `value` attribute, so it is invalid HTML. Use custom `data-*` attributes.
2. `current` is the `name` of element, not `id`. Use `attribute selector` to select element by an attribute.
3. `ready` should be called on `document`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('span[name="current"]').data('value') == 'Dispatch') {
    alert('Dispatch');
  } else {
    alert('Nothing found');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span name="current" data-value="Dispatch">Dispatch</span>
<!--                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            -->
```

Comment: Much better :) `data-` usage is a good suggestions. Note: the original HTML is also "just plain broken" (no closing `</span>`, unclosed bolding)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".table").find("tr td:nth-child(1)").text();
```

Comment: No `$.trim`? Text comparison of content is unreliable due to changing content, but this is especially wrong when the original was attempting to use a custom attribute. Changing that to a `data-` attribute would be the correct solution. As per @Tushar. Also, using `nth-child(1)` when a name attribute exists is just making it more complicated than necessary.